# how to query string with operator symbols in Postgres/Prisma?

Tags: postgresql, prisma

This is how I query in my Postgres database.

```js
    const params = request.nextUrl.searchParams.get('q');
    const query = `%${params}%`;
    const langs = await prisma.$queryRaw`
    SELECT lang 
    FROM "ProgrammingLanguages" 
    WHERE lang ILIKE ${query} 
    ORDER BY LENGTH(lang) ASC;`;
```

This works for me, it is a database containing programming languages.

For example, when I query `'c'` I get the following results:

```
[
  {
    "lang": "c"
  },
  {
    "lang": "c#"
  },
  {
    "lang": "css"
  },
  {
    "lang": "c++"
  },
  {
    "lang": "scala"
  },
  {
    "lang": "javascript"
  },
  {
    "lang": "typescript"
  }
]
```

But the problem lies here: when you query `c+` or `c++` nothing shows up.

```
[]
```

How do you query `c++` in this case?

I didn't know what to try.

Answer (score 0):

found it: use `encodeURIComponent(query)` it encodes `+` to `'%2B'`